# Como inserir ícones no projeto Android?

Tags: android

Eu estou criando botões de menu no meu projeto Android, para isso estou usando o site do [Material IO](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/), para eu conseguir incluir os ícones. O que eu fiz foi baixar as imagens do ícones como mostra na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois eu descompactei no meu computador local e peguei a pasta onde estava os ícones e colei no diretório **RES** como mostra na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você podem ver mesmo eu ter colado no projeto as pastas elas simplesmente não aparecem, ou seja, o projeto não reconhecem as pastas que colei, e elas realmente estão lá, eu naveguei até a raiz do projeto e encontrei elas lá como podem ver na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, como faço para meu projeto reconhecer essas pastas que acabei de colocar no projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde wladyband...
para criar estas pastas você deve clicar com o **botão direito** na pasta **res**, em seguida selecionar **new** e depois **android resource directory**...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, selecionar o nome e o tipo do diretório...

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?